# Javascript/Java HTML template/data-binding library

Tags: java, javascript, html, templates, toolkit

I'd like to find out about libraries with the following properties:

- Javascript implementation for client-side,
- Java implementation for server-side,
- light-weight syntax: no generic 'code', only simple expressions,
- but simple for-loops, 'include', and 'if'.

(In short, the syntax would be similar to Django templates, if that tells you anything.)

Does anybody know an open-source library that fulfills these requirements?

Comment: This question is not of "comparative" nature, rather it is about "existence". It should not get closed IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)?  It offers very simple templates and can be used in both [java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) and [javascript](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

If you look at the docs you can see simple examples of loops:

```
{{#names}}
  Hi {{name}}!
{{/names}}
```

and conditions:

```
{{#value}}
  Value was true
{{/value}}
{{^value}}
  Value was false
{{/value}}
```

Includes can be handled by using partials, which let you pull in another template.

Comment: Looks promising! Not just JS + Java, which is only a plus, of course.